# MapView throwing IllegalArgumentException - Wrong Image Size: 192 192

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, illegalargumentexception

I'm getting excessive crash reports from users on a Samsung Vibrant Galaxy S.  After searching around for solutions to this issue, the only thing I came across was an open issue over at Google Code:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4599

The thread suggests extending MapView and catching the exceptions.  Is this the best approach, or is there something better?  I'd like to completely fix this issue rather than throw a bandage on it.

Here's the Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong image size: 192 192
at com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile.getImage(Unknown Source)
at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawTile(Unknown Source)
at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMap(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.drawMap(MapView.java:1048)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:486)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6597)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1533)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1260)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1260)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6600)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1533)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1260)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6600)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1884)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1374)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1139)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1658)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully someone else will show up with another answer to prove me wrong, but in my personal experience with device-specific issues, catching the exceptions often seems to be the best you can do.

**Edit regarding your comment below:** That is a point, and I did run into some new problems with specific devices using customised WebView code when extending WebView once.

There are a ton of people on here with far more experience than me, and I hope one of them will drop in to give a more definitive answer or less hacky solution, but if necessary, you could always use `android.os.Build.DEVICE`, `android.os.Build.MODEL` and/or `android.os.Build.PRODUCT` to determine whether the app is running on a Samsung Vibrant Galaxy S, and (via reflection) use the custom MapView class only if it is.

Comment: This is understandable but the problem with this is that working around the issue for those who account for 1% of the app usage may lead to problems with the users accounting for the other 99%.  Are there any gotchas when extending the MapView that I don't know about?  This is my main concern about "working around" this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I may have to end up going with something like in your edit.  I'll give it some more time to see if anybody else has a complete fix or a different solution.

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer, as it is a workable solution, just not desired.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be You have done mistake here, so change the code to correct form, or enter

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"   // in manifest under inside applicaiton tag
              android:required="true"/>


//wrong usage of activity
 public class A extends Actvitiy 
 {
  }
    //correct usage
  public class A extedns MapsActivity 
 {
      //your all program...
   }
```